# Transpose of certain related columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am new to R. I was trying do a transpose of data frame without luck. Tried using t(dataframe), melt(dataframe) but not getting the output as I want.

The original data frame as following

```
CAT1   CAT2   VAL1   VAL2
A1     A2     BLUE   BLUE
B1     B2     GREEN  GREEN
C1     C2     BLUE   BLUE
```

I want to transpose this data frame in such way so that it looks like the following and VAL1 and VAL2 works grouping variable.

```
VAL    CAT

BLUE   A1    
       A2
BLUE   C1
       C2
GREEN  B1
       B2
```

I am wondering if this is achievable.

Here is the code to create the first dataset:

```
dt <-data.frame('CAT1' = c('A1','B1','C1'),
                'CAT2' = c('A2','B2','C2'),
                'VAL1' = c('BLUE','RED','GREEN'),
                'VAL2' = c('BLUE','RED','GREEN'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `reshape` will get you close.

```
dt_long <- reshape(dt, varying = list(c('CAT1','CAT2'),
                                      c('VAL1','VAL2')), 
                       sep = "",
                       direction = "long")
dt_long
#    time CAT1  VAL1 id
#1.1    1   A1  BLUE  1
#2.1    1   B1   RED  2
#3.1    1   C1 GREEN  3
#1.2    2   A2  BLUE  1
#2.2    2   B2 BLACK  2
#3.2    2   C2   RED  3
```

Now you would need to exclude the unneeded columns, as in `dt_long[, c("CAT1", "VAL1")]`.

Also, if you have column names a la "CAT1, CAT2, ... CATn", instead of typing n names, do `paste0("CAT", 1:n)`.

---

**update**

Based on the new requirement we can create column `VAL` as

```
dt_long$VAL <- c(rbind(unique(dt_long$VAL1), NA))
#    CAT1  VAL1   VAL
#1.1   A1  BLUE  BLUE
#1.2   A2  BLUE  <NA>
#2.1   B1   RED   RED
#2.2   B2   RED  <NA>
#3.1   C1 GREEN GREEN
#3.2   C2 GREEN  <NA>
```

Furthermore, to generate the vector `c("VAL11, VAL12, VAL21, VAL22, VAL31, VAL32")` we can do

```
paste0("VAL", c(sapply(1:3, paste0, 1:2)))
#[1] "VAL11" "VAL12" "VAL21" "VAL22" "VAL31" "VAL32"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @markus, thanks for the help, but looking at your comment I felt like I need to edit  the question I had earlier. So I have edited the question. Please have a look and let me if it is possible to do, Thanks again

Comment: @HelenNdp Sorry for the delay. What do you want those blank cell to be? Empty strings, i.e. `""` or `NA`s? I'd recommend `NA`s.

Comment: Hi @markus,   Yes, thanks NA's will be good, that's just for easy to see, so wanted to make it look such a way that it feels like a group. I had one more question. Since I have VAL 1 and VAL2 that's why the code works just fine, but if its like `VAL11` `VAL12`    `VAL21` `VAL22`    `VAL31` `VAL32` shall I just put `varying = list(c('CAT1','CAT2'),c('VAL11','VAL12'),c('VAL21','VAL22'),c('VAL31','VAL32'))`. Though it not seems like a very good idea.

Comment: @HelenNdp Updated the answer. Let me know if something is unclear or missing. Best